# Why do I have @angular/core in node_modules, but still get this error?

Tags: node.js, angular, web, npm, angular2-routing

I downloaded an example project from angular.io , from here
https://angular.io/generated/zips/cli-quickstart/cli-quickstart.zip

and ran npm install in the root folder, as in this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJKejcQJqHE

and somewhy, although I have the corresponding angular packages in both node_modules and package.json, still I got this:

```
Hash: faeff28da7a6ba00851d                    
Time: 8547ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 171 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 5.41 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 11.5 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.18 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/app/app.component.ts (1,27): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/app/app.component.ts (8,14): Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/app/app.module.ts (1,31): Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/app/app.module.ts (2,26): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/app/app.module.ts (16,14): Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/main.ts (1,32): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/main.ts (2,40): Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.

ERROR in Could not resolve module @angular/core
webpack: Failed to compile.
webpack: Compiling...
Hash: faeff28da7a6ba00851d                                               
Time: 807ms
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 171 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 5.41 kB {3} [initial]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 11.5 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.18 MB [initial]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry]

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/app/app.component.ts (1,27): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/app/app.component.ts (8,14): Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/app/app.module.ts (1,31): Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser'.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/app/app.module.ts (2,26): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/app/app.module.ts (16,14): Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/main.ts (1,32): Cannot find module '@angular/core'.

ERROR in /home/ivan/anglr-lrn/src/main.ts (2,40): Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic'.
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked in a similar situation:

**Uninstall NodeJS on your machine**.

If installed with the downloadable package installer - (Add Remove Programs > Select NodeJS and click uninstall)

Download and install NodeJS 6.10.3 (https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.3/node-v6.10.3-x64.msi)

**Clean-up node_modules folder**

`rm -rf node_modules/`

**Clean-up any temp folders**

**Run these commands**

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install
```